# Photoshop Color Accuracy Per Window

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have multiple images open in Photoshop CS6, all with the same color mode of RGB. When I use the color picker to select a color in image #1, and then move to image #2, the color drastically changes for no reason and becomes brighter.  Also, when I select the color in image #2 and copy the hex code, it produces a color code that is not true to what was selected.  I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: all documents in RGB mode?

Comment: Yes they are all RGB mode.  But converting out of RGB and back again seems to solve the problem.

Comment: different color profiles?